# Prevent onkeyup event when input field first gets focus

Tags: javascript, jsf, dom-events, richfaces

I have a component I want called on each `keyup` event by the user.

The problem is I do not want to call it when the user first tabs into the text box (`onfocus`).

How can I get around this in JSF/Richfaces? Do I need to combine some Javascript to get around it?

```
<h:inputText id="limit1" value="#{bean.purchaseTypeItem.subPurchaseLimit}" immediate="true">
    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.BigDecimal" />
    <f:attribute name="fieldRef" value="Purchase Limit1" />
    <a4j:support event="onkeyup" ajaxSingle="true" immediate="true" requestDelay="200" 
        actionListener="#{bean.validateAmount}" ignoreDupResponses="true" reRender="main"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

I put in a check to prevent the ajax call firing if the user tabbed into the input box.
The addition of the extra a4j:support component is to allow the ajax call when tabbing out of the input box.

```
<h:inputText id="limit1" value="#{bean.purchaseTypeItem.subPurchaseLimit}" immediate="true">
    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.BigDecimal" />
    <f:attribute name="fieldRef" value="Purchase Limit1" />
    <a4j:support event="onkeyup" ajaxSingle="true" immediate="true" requestDelay="200" 
        actionListener="#{bean.validateAmount}" ignoreDupResponses="true" reRender="main"  
    onsubmit="if(event.keyCode == 9){return false;}" />
    <a4j:support event="onblur" ajaxSingle="true" immediate="true"
    requestDelay="200" actionListener="#{bean.validateAmount}"
    ignoreDupResponses="true" reRender="main" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Thomas! The version of your own solution for richfaces 4 JSR-303 (bean validation) is ...

```
<rich:validator event="keyup" onbeforesubmit="if(event.keyCode == 9){return false;}"/>
```